# How can I see grants in role?

Tags: amazon-redshift

After

```
grant select on db.table to role MASTER_ROLE; 
grant role MASTER_ROLE to myuser;
```

I would like to see which grants each role has, and which users have each role. I'm used to use `has_table_privilege` but this shows the individual-user-grant-base permissions and not role-based.